# Expectation of absolute value of sum of 2 random variables with conditions

Tags: self-study, random-variable, expected-value, sum

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that
$E(X+Y)=E(X-Y)=0$ and
$Var(X+Y)=3$ and
$Var(X-Y)=1$ then how to show that $E(|X+Y|)\leq \sqrt3$

Guidelines asap would help me
thanks.

Comment: Maybe I am just being dumb because ti is early in the morning, but I don't think this question makes sense. $$E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y) = E(X)-E(Y)$$
which means
$$E(Y)=-E(Y)$$
which is only true for zero mean RVs I guess

Comment: Y can have expected value 0 without violating the results given in the question.  In fact since E(X+Y)= E(X)+E(Y) and E(Y)=0, E(X)=0 too.

Comment: Also using the fact that Var(X+Y)=Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 Cov(X,Y) = 3 and Var(X -Y)= Var(X) + Var(Y) - 2 Cov(X,Y) = 1 you get using some algebra Cov(X,Y) = 1/2. Now it remains to find an inequality involving |X+Y| to get the result.

Comment: You need to add the self-study tag to get further guidance to lead you to the answer.

Comment: how to determine E(|X|) here? if I could do that maybe I can use holder's inequality. Please help me thanks..

Comment: Compare $E(X^2)=E(|X|^2)$ to $E(|X|)^2$ using, say, Jensen's Inequality or merely the fact that variances are non-negative.